# Typescript named function different behaviour. Error Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript, types

```
type ResolverFn = () => any;

// type Notifications = () => any | number; // works as expected
type Notifications = ResolverFn | number; 
// when using the named function, ResolverFn, it fails with  error:
// "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Notifications' has no compatible call signatures."
// but it works with the unnamed () => any

type Query = {
  notifications: Notifications;
};

const Query: Query = {
  notifications() {}
};


const notifications: Notifications = () => {};

notifications();
Query.notifications();
```

The above example is very simple and it is deducted from a more complex one. In reality there isn't a type which signature is either a function or a number. Here it's simply used to showcase the difference in behaviour.

There are other questions related to this error but I couldn't find an answer to my specific question, which is:

Why is there a different behaviour with the named and unnamed function? Is this expected behaviour? Why? Is there a workaround? Assume the issue is coming from an external package that we can't modify, even if it may be incorrect.

[Typescript repl](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ResolverFn%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20Notifications%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20any%20%7C%20number%3B%20%2F%2F%20works%20as%20expected%0D%0Atype%20Notifications%20%3D%20ResolverFn%20%7C%20number%3B%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20when%20using%20the%20named%20function%2C%20ResolverFn%2C%20it%20fails%20with%20%20error%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%22Cannot%20invoke%20an%20expression%20whose%20type%20lacks%20a%20call%20signature.%20Type%20'Notifications'%20has%20no%20compatible%20call%20signatures.%22%0D%0A%2F%2F%20but%20it%20works%20with%20the%20unnamed%20()%20%3D%3E%20any%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Query%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20notifications%3A%20Notifications%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20Query%3A%20Query%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20notifications()%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20notifications%3A%20Notifications%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Anotifications()%3B%0D%0AQuery.notifications()%3B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the inlined function type "works" is because it doesn't do what you think it does: it describes a function returning `any | number` due to precedence rules. Note the difference:

```
// A function returning either any or number 
type A = () => any | number;

// Either a function returning any — or a number 
type B = (() => any) | number;
```

And the reason it otherwise doesn't work is because it's not clear that `notifications` is of the function type, it could also be a number, and numbers aren't callable.

As pointed out in @Przemyslaw Pietrzak's answer, use a type guard to narrow the type:

```
if (typeof notifications === "function") {
    notifications();
}
```

Comment: Oh, the facepalm was hard. Could you just add the ` if (typeof query.notifications === 'function') ` solution for sake of completeness?

Comment: Done! I also referenced Przemyslaw Pietrzak's answer since he pointed it out first.

Answer (score 2):

Look Notification type can be either number or function. So in the last line TS is not sure that `Query.notifications` can be safety called because it can be also number and in that case code will throw error in runtime.

To prevent that error add if statement:

```js
if (typeof query.notifications === 'function') {
  query.notifications();
}
```

inside if TS knows that `query.notifications` is not a number so it can be safety called.